# Java - create a two player game

Tags: java

Trying to create a play for this game I'm building, yet it is giving me an error that I am not understanding. What I need it to do is create a player and display the username and score points for each player. The error I am getting is in the player class because I believe the code I have is not correct. I need help please this project is due in 2 hours and I am struggling a lot.

> **CAI.java**

```
package cai;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class CAI {
    private int correct;

    public CAI() {
        resetCorrect(0);
    }
    private String Username;
    public int getCorrect(){
        return correct;
    }
    void Addition(){
        for(int count = 1; count <= 10; count++){
            System.out.println("Problem " + count + " of 10:");
            correct += this.doAddition();
        }
    }

    public int doAddition(){
        int count = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random g = new Random();
        int first = g.nextInt(10);
        int second = g.nextInt(10);
        int answer = first + second;
        String toString = first + " + " + second + " = " + answer;

        while (count <= 3){

            count++;

            System.out.print(first + " + " + second + " = ");

            int userAnswer = scan.nextInt();

            if (userAnswer == answer){

                this.printGoodComment();

                count = 10; //used as a flag value

            }else{
                if (count != 4){
                    this.printBadComment();
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 10){
            return 1;
        }else{
            this.printFailure(toString);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void Substraction(){
        for(int count = 1; count <= 10; count++){
            System.out.println("Problem " + count + " of 10:");
            correct += this.doSubstract();
        }
    }

    public int doSubstract(){
        int count = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random g = new Random();
        int first = g.nextInt(10);
        int second = g.nextInt(10);
        int answer = first - second;
        String toString = first + " - " + second + " = " + answer;
        while (count <= 3){
            count++;
            System.out.print(first + " - " + second + " = ");
            int userAnswer = scan.nextInt();
            if (userAnswer == answer){
                this.printGoodComment();
                count = 10; //used as a flag value
            }else{
                if (count != 4){
                    this.printBadComment();
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 10){
            return 1;
        }else{
            this.printFailure(toString);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void multplication(){
        for(int count = 1; count <= 10; count++){
            System.out.println("Problem " + count + " of 10:");
            correct += this.doMultiply();
        }
    }

    public int doMultiply(){
        int count = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random g = new Random();
        int first = g.nextInt(10);
        int second = g.nextInt(10);
        int answer = first * second;
        String toString = first + " * " + second + " = " + answer;
        while (count <= 3){
            count++;

            System.out.print(first + " * " + second + " = ");
            int userAnswer = scan.nextInt();
            if (userAnswer == answer){
                this.printGoodComment();
                count = 10; //used as a flag value
            }else{
                if (count != 4){
                    this.printBadComment();
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 10){
            return 1;
        }else{
            this.printFailure(toString);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    void Division(){
        for(int count = 1; count <= 10; count++){
            System.out.println("Problem " + count + " of 10:");
            correct += this.doDivide();
        }
    }

    public int doDivide(){
        int count = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random g = new Random();
        int first = g.nextInt(10);
        int second = g.nextInt(10);
        int answer = first / second;
        String toString = first + " / " + second + " = " + answer;
        while (count <= 3){
            count++;
            System.out.print(first + " / " + second + " = ");
            int userAnswer = scan.nextInt();
            if (userAnswer == answer){
                this.printGoodComment();
                count = 10; //used as a flag value
            }else{
                if (count != 4){
                    this.printBadComment();
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 10){
            return 1;
        }else{
            this.printFailure(toString);
            return 0;
        }
    }



    public void printFailure(String answer){
        System.out.println("Incorrect Solution");
        System.out.println("Solution is: " + answer);
    }

    public void resetCorrect(int n) {
        correct = n;
    }

    /* Print math drill menu. */
    public void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my CAI");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Substraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division");
        System.out.println("\nPlease select the operation , or Q to quit: ");
    }

    public void printGoodComment(){
        Random g = new Random();
        int n = g.nextInt(4)+1; // n is between 1 - 4
        switch (n){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Very good!");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Excellent!");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Nice Work!");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Keep up the Good Work!");
            break;
        }

    }
        public void printBadComment(){
            Random g = new Random();
            int n = g.nextInt(4)+1; // n is between 1 - 4
            switch (n){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("No. Please try again.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Wrong. Try once more.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Don't give up");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("No. Keep trying");
                break;
        }


    }

}
```

> **player.java**

```
package cai;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Player {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Player[] players = new Player[10];

    int totalPlayers = 0;
    Player player1 = new Player("Yohana");
    players[0] = player1;
    totalPlayers++;

    Player player2 = new Player("Nick");
    players[1] = player2;
    totalPlayers++;



    System.out.println("Player 1: " + players[0]);
    System.out.println("Player 2: " + players[1]);

        int c;
        CAI m = new CAI();
        System.out.println("This program was written by my name.\n");
        m.printMenu();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice=in.next();

       while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
    if (choice.equals("Addition")){
           m.Addition();
    }else if (choice.equals("Substraction")){
           m.Substraction();
    }else if (choice.equals("Multiplication")){
           m.multplication();
    }else if (choice.equals("Division")){
          m.Division();

    }



        System.out.println("You got " + m.getCorrect() + " right. " + m.getCorrect() + "0%");

        if ( (double)m.getCorrect() / 10 < .75){
            System.out.println("Please ask your instuctor for extra help.");
        }

           m.resetCorrect(0);
           m.printMenu();
           choice=in.next();
        }
    }

    private Player (String name)
    {
        String Username = name;
    }
    //used for printing
    public String toString()
    {
    return String.format("$s:", Username);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you actually getting?

Comment: and what is not correct? you´re getting an exception? doesn´t it compile? is the output different from your expected output?

Comment: It doesnt create the player

Comment: Could you please post the code for `CAI.java`?

Comment: ok one moment!!!

Comment: Then why class name is `Player.java`?

Comment: @BowlsToGo your public class here is called `Player` and as though it should be `Player.java`

Comment: Even if it is `CAI.java`, where are method definitions for Addition, Substraction, etc? Where the variable `Username` is defined? Why `Player` (the constructor?) is private?

Comment: What is printed out at this point `System.out.println("Player 1: " + players[0]);` when you actually run the program?

Comment: `Username` still remains undeclared. You need to declare it as a field so `toString()` can see it

Comment: First thing (or one of the first things) you wanna tackle is to use `%` instead of `$` in your string formatting

Comment: Please also add a short description of the `CAI` class. You could also help yourself by describing the mechanics of your game.

Comment: what do u mean by a short description to the cai class?

Comment: because this line is showing as an error to me   CAI m = player.new CAI();  @jrook

Comment: can you please tell me @jrook  CAI m = player.new CAI(); is showing as an error why?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected code to resolve compile errors but you should provide implementations of methods of class CAI.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    private String username;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player("Bowls");
        CAI m = player.new CAI();
        Player[] players = new Player[10];

        int totalPlayers = 0;
        Player player1 = new Player("Yohana");
        players[0] = player1;
        totalPlayers++;

        Player player2 = new Player("Nick");
        players[1] = player2;
        totalPlayers++;

        System.out.println("Player 1: " + players[0]);
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + players[1]);

        int c;
        System.out.println("This program was written by my name.\n");
        m.printMenu();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = in.next();

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            if (choice.equals("Addition")) {
                m.Addition();
            } else if (choice.equals("Substraction")) {
                m.Substraction();
            } else if (choice.equals("Multiplication")) {
                m.multplication();
            } else if (choice.equals("Division")) {
                m.Division();

            }

            System.out.println("You got " + m.getCorrect() + " right. " + m.getCorrect() + "0%");

            if ((double) m.getCorrect() / 10 < .75) {
                System.out.println("Please ask your instuctor for extra help.");
            }

            m.resetCorrect(0);
            m.printMenu();
            choice = in.next();
        }
    }

    private Player(String name) {
        username = name;
    }

    // used for printing
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("$s:", username);
    }

    class CAI {

        public CAI() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void printMenu() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void resetCorrect(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public double getCorrect() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public void Division() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void multplication() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void Substraction() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void Addition() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In, `return String.format("$s:", username);` , `$` needs to be `%`